# prestashop compare button in product list

Tags: php, compare, task-parallel-library, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I want to add the compare button (existing in product.tpl) to product-list.tpl, i've try to copy the code existing in product.tpl

```
{if isset($comparator_max_item) && $comparator_max_item}
        <div class="compare">
        <a class="add_to_compare" href="#" data-id-product="{$product->id|intval}" style="color:black;"><i class="fas fa-cubes" style="font-size:1.3em;padding-right:.4em;"></i> {l s='Add to Compare'}</a>
        </div>
        {/if}
        {include file="./product-compare.tpl"}
        </div>

        {*Products compare *}
        {addJsDefL name=min_item}{l s='Please select at least one product' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
        {addJsDefL name=max_item}{l s='You cannot add more than %d product(s) to the product comparison' sprintf=$comparator_max_item js=1}{/addJsDefL}
        {addJsDef comparator_max_item=$comparator_max_item}
        {addJsDef comparedProductsIds=$compared_products}
```

To product-list.tpl

```
<div class="compare_product_page">    
        {if isset($comparator_max_item) && $comparator_max_item}
        <div class="compare">
        <a class="add_to_compare add_to_compare_list" href="#" data-id-product="{$product->id|intval}" style="color:black;"><i class="fas fa-cubes" style="font-size:1.3em;padding-right:.4em;"></i> {l s='Add to Compare'}</a>
        </div>
        {/if}
        
        </div>

       
        {addJsDefL name=min_item}{l s='Please select at least one product' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
        {addJsDefL name=max_item}{l s='You cannot add more than %d product(s) to the product comparison' sprintf=$comparator_max_item js=1}{/addJsDefL}
        {addJsDef comparator_max_item=$comparator_max_item}
        {addJsDef comparedProductsIds=$compared_products}
```

I don't know what i'm missing...can someone give some lights?

Comment: Perhaps `$comparator_max_item` doesn’t actually exist in the scope of that template …?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your time, i think that exists because in product detail (product.tpl) all works fine.

Comment: Why would you assume that two different templates, used to create two separate views, would get the exact same set of external parameters passed in?

Comment: @CBroe point taken, i will check it...thanks.